# How can I create a controller route and have a default action plus check for type of parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an address like the following:

```
www.stack.com/Content/00000/solutions-about
```

How can I specify in my route that when the URL above will

```
a) go to the Content controller
b) action of Get
c) five digits that follow will be put into a parameter called id?
```

Also how can I make this go to another action such as "error" if the "Content/" is not followed by five numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Content",
    "Content/{id}/{something}",
    new { controller = "Content", action = "Get" },
    new { id = @"^\d{5}$" }
);
```